# It is possible to use MRKT and HTC VIVE for creating Augmented Reality app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive, mrtk

I'm working on an augmented reality app.

I planned to use Hololens for deploying my app using Mixed Reality ToolKiT.
In the documentation, I learn that Mixed Reality toolkit can be used for many devices as HTC VIVE.

Even Hololens is dedicated for augmented reality app and HTC Vive for virtual reality, it seems that HTC vive can be an augmented reality hardware.

Is it possible to create augmented reality app using HTC VIVE and MRTK, or combining HTC VIVE and MRTK is just for virtual reality?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you find an answer ? As a 3d headset has cameras, if we can access their buffers we should be able to render them behind the scene and have AR, but I didn't find how.

Answer (score 0):

The MRTK can be used for AR and VR devices. In principle the same app can run on a Hololens and a Vive.

But the virtual camera background and the input is handled different. Hololens has a transparent display, so it's camera background is also transparent and vive has an opaque display and a background you want, e.g. a Skymap so it's VR. The Input is also mapped for the specific device. Hololens uses usually AirTaps and Vive joystick input devices. https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Overview.html

There are some platform specific APIs like spatial mapping, that's only working with the Hololens.